# How does Jenkins send email notifications to Subversion users?

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

subversion does not have email id. They only have username and password authentication. Now in Jenkins if build fails, how do I send emails to the particular culprit who broke the build. Please suggest to me how Jenkins will take email id from subversion user and how does it send it.

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins will create some internal users based on the information it gets from the svn commits. It also configures a default e-mail address from the username and the **Default user e-mail suffix** setup under the global config (Configure Jenkins -> Configure System -> Default user e-mail suffix)

If the SVN usernames are different from your company's email usernames and if you have administrative privileges, you can access all the Jenkins users by clicking on the **People** link located in the upper left corner of the screen. From here, you can click on any user from the displayed list, and then also on the left side of the screen you should have a **Configure** link. Once you click that, you should see an interface which allows you to change several details, including the e-mail address.

You may also want to check the [ext-email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) which provide more flexibility, and if you decide to use it please note the following statement from the docs:

> **Include Culprits** - If this is checked AND Send To Developers is checked, emails will include everyone who committed since the last successful build.

Answer (score 0):

svn only provides you with the username.

for example if your user name is "spongebob". the email when a build failed feature will try to email strait to spongebob
you have two options.

1) if your SVN user names fit your company email addresses you can set it settings to autocomplete domain name

means email send lugin will get "spongebob" and will autocomplete it to 
spongebob@yourcompay.com

2) if the names are different or people may have diffrent domains you can map

i dont use jenkins anymore so dont have the extact names in front of me.
but this should set you in the right path.

Comment: subversion usernames and  email id are  different for example user name is James and his email id is jamesbob@company.com

Comment: In the main jenkins settings in the email tab. you can MAP a name to email.